# Filling Progress Bar (widen div) with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to widen a div (simulating a process bar) when the element is onscreen. I cant get anything to happen. What am I doing wrong? I am trying to use:

**jQuery**

```
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            if ($('.progressFull').isOnScreen() == true) {
                $(this).animate({
                    'width': '1000%'
                }, 2000);
            }
        });
    });
```

**html**

```
    <div class="skillsCol">
        <ul>

            <li><a class="skill">C++</a>
                <div class="progress"></div>
                <div class="progressFull"></div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
```

**css**

```
    #
    skills {
        background - color: white;
    }
        .skillsCol li {
            list - style - type: none;
    }

    .skillsCol {
        width: 45 % ;
    }

    .progress {
        width: 25 % ;
        height: 2 % ;
        margin - left: 50 % ;
        margin - top: -5.4 % ;
        border: 1px solid black;
        z - index: 1;
    }

    .progressFull {
        background: #7688A9;
        width: 0%;
        height: 2%;
        margin-left: 50%;
        margin-top: -4.1%;
        z-index: 5;
    }
```

Comment: Looks like you're widening the Window, not the div. `$(this).animate` affects the Window because of the command being run on `$(window)` from two lines before.

Answer (score 0):

`this` refers to window object there, you probably want to refer to `.progress` or `.progressFull` element.

```
$('.progressFull').animate({ 'width' : '1000%' }, 2000);
```

Comment: thanks! is there a way to reset the width back to 0 when the element is no longer on the screen?

Comment: this way always starts the meter a soon as the scroll bar is pressed. thisn section of my site is on the bottom of my page. is there a way to wait until is is visible in the viewport?

Answer (score 0):

First you didn't have enough height to scroll. So, window scroll not applied.

Apply following way:

```
<div class="skillsCol">
        <ul>

            <li><a class="skill">C++</a>
                <div class="progress"></div>
                <div class="progressFull"></div>
            </li>

        </ul>
    </div>
<div style="height: 2000px;"></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.skills {
        background - color: white;
    }
        .skillsCol li {
            list - style - type: none;
    }

    .skillsCol {
        width: 45 % ;
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    }

    .progress {
        width: 0;
        height: 2 % ;
        margin - left: 50 % ;
        margin - top: -5.4 % ;
        border: 1px solid black;
        z - index: 1;
    }

    .progressFull {
        background: #7688A9;
        width: 0;
        height: 2%;
        margin-left: 50%;
        margin-top: -4.1%;
        z-index: 5;
    }
```

Check: [Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Mvf67/1927/)

Comment: this way always starts the meter a soon as the scroll bar is pressed. thisn section of my site is on the bottom of my page. is there a way to wait until is is visible in the viewport?

Comment: @MattEm for that you should use `window load` instead of document ready in jquery.